# SAXParseException lists optional values

Tags: java, sax

I am getting the following UnmarshalException in a Java 1.8.0_191 program running on Windows 10, that uses classes generated using the jaxb2 Maven plugin version 2.5.0 to process incoming XML SOAP requests:

```
JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 622; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a : Contenu non valide trouvé à partir del'élément 'MotifCommande'. L'une des valeurs '{AliasCde,RefExterneCde, DateDepot}' est attendue.]
```

Here's a quick translation in English of the Exception message:

> Invalid content found starting with the MotifCommand item. One of the
>   items '{AliasCd, RefExterneCde, DateDepot}' is expected.

Strangely enough, the item list mentions two optional fields (AliasCD and RefExterneCde) and one mandatory field (DateDepot). Why not just the mandatory field?

Furthermore, why does the message state that the content is invalid starting with the MotifCommande tag, although the latter appears *after* the (mandatory) DateDepot tag, in the XSD?

The XSDs and SOAP Request as available as a zip, on this website: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/185

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message lists all elements that are allowed at the position in the document. This also includes optional elements. It is an error if anything else appears.

The relevant part in the XML schema is this:

```xml
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="SystemeRefCde" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
  <xsd:element name="AliasCde" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xsd:element name="RefExterneCde" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xsd:element name="DateDepot" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
  <!-- ... -->
  <xsd:element name="MotifCommande" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
```

You are using a sequence. Thus the order of items is relevant.
This means, after `SystemeRefCde` only the optinoal elements `AliasCde` or `RefExterneCde` and after those, the mandatory element `DateDepot` may appear.
Every other element results in a schema violation.

In your request, you have:

```xml
<RefCommande>32R69010200004101415</RefCommande>
<SystemeRefCde>32R</SystemeRefCde>

<MotifCommande>ORDST</MotifCommande>
```

After `SystemeRefCde` the next element in the sequence is `MotifCommande`. This is not allowed by the XSD. You are missing at least the mandatory `DateDepot` element in between.